# how to use max function in python pandas I'm getting the wrong number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataset.

| ID | age | Region | nationality | IsHypertension | IsDiabetesType2 | Weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 40 | ABB | US | 1 | Nan | 90 | 170 |
| 123 | 40 | ABB | US | Nan | 1 | 90 | 170 |

I need my dataset to be like this (unique Id):

| ID | age | Region | nationality | IsHypertension | IsDiabetesType2 | Weight | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 40 | ABB | US | 1 | 1 | 90 | 170 |

I tried this code

```
user = df.groupby(['ID', 'Age', 'Region', 'nationality','Weight','Height'], as_index=False).max()
```

The result of this code gives me fewer rows than the number of unique ID before I ran this code!
The rows must match the number of unique ID not lower and not higher

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, the current one is behaving as expected. Do you have NaNs in the unique IDs?

Comment: I have NaN in (IsHypertension) , (IsDiabetesType2)

Comment: What is the output of `(len(df['ID'].unique()), len(df['ID'].dropna().unique()))`? And of `(len(df.groupby(['ID', 'age', 'Region', 'nationality','Weight','height'], as_index=False, dropna=True)), len(df.groupby(['ID', 'age', 'Region', 'nationality','Weight','height'], as_index=False, dropna=False))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
cols_max = ['IsHypertension', 'IsDiabetesType2', 'Weight', 'height']
user = df.groupby(
    ['ID', 'Age', 'Region', 'nationality'], 
    as_index=False
).agg(
    {col: 'max' for col in cols_max}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fill first `nan` values with `bfill` and `ffill` methods and then drop duplicates.

Following code keeps first identical row by default.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 123],
                   'age': [40, 40],
                   'Region': ["ABB", "ABB"],
                   'nationality': ["US", "US"],
                   'IsHypertension': [1, np.nan],
                   'IsDiabetesType2': [np.nan, 1], 
                   'Weight': [90, 90],
                   'height': [170, 170],
                   })

r = df.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()

print(r)
```

**Result**

```
    ID  age Region nationality  IsHypertension  IsDiabetesType2  Weight  height
0  123   40    ABB          US             1.0              1.0      90     170
```